# Reuse the ResultSet and call in multiple classes in java

Tags: java, database

I have a method `getalldetails` (query) which will get details from the database. I want to call this method in multiple classes and based on query. It should fetch the data from the database. Query will be passed dynamically. I am trying to do in following way. Please correct me and advise me hwo to use only one method for data retrieval in whole project.

I am facing these issues:

1. Return type of result set and calling of method and re use of result. Please guide me and help me

For eg: In DatabaseDAO.java class

```
public class DatabaseDAO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        public ResultSet getalldetails(String query){
         ResultSet rs = null;
         try{
           PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            } 
        catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return rs;  
           } 
         }
```

Suppose , I have two classes Employee and Product.java. I want to call this method in both classes . Below is my code:

```
public class Employee {
String query ="Select * from Employee";
ResultSet rs=null;
List<EmployeeDto> emp= new ArrayList<EmployeeDto>();
DatabaseDAO.getalldetails(query);
while (rs .has next)
{
 EmployeeDto qd=new EmployeeDto();                      
 qd.setidrs.getInt("id"));
 qd.setname(rs.getString("name"));
 qd.setrollno(rs.getString("rollno"));
  emp.add(qd);
 }
}
```

Similarly, I have Product.java . I want to call same method to retrieval data form DB based on query based.

```
public class Product {
String query ="Select * from Product";
ResultSet rs=null;
List<ProductDto> emp= new ArrayList<ProductDto>();
DatabaseDAO.getalldetails(query);
while (rs .has next)
{
 ProductDto qd=new ProductDto();                        
 pd.setidrs.getInt("prodid"));
 pd.setname(rs.getString("prodname"));
 pd.setrollno(rs.getString("item"));
  prod.add(pd);
 }
}
```

I want to use one method in whole project to retrieve the data from DB . Means I want to do reusability of method. Please help me on this.

Comment: Why have you put a method inside another method? Why have you put a bunch of statements directly inside classes? Why is your code indented like it has been dropped on the floor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing dynamically query to prepared statement and reuse the function in different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440533/passing-dynamically-query-to-prepared-statement-and-reuse-the-function-in-differ)

Comment: @khelwood, please reply me with correction of code. SO that i can learn from you as i am in beginner in java

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a **static** method in a class. Say Database. And you can access it anywhere by importing the `Database` class and calling `Database.getalldetails (query)`

As an aside, i see in your code, that you have defined `getalldetails` inside the `main` method. You should put it outside.
In the `Employee` class, you place code inside a class, but outside a method/constructor. Add a Constructor or a method and put the code there

Comment: Khelwood and Kristjan, please correct me with corrected code as i am beginner and your help will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This can be an example of your concept.

I call it a DBMain class which has a entry point of bot classes, the Product and the Employee class by the DatabaseDAO class.

First, make an instance of the DatabaseDAO class then initialize the database connection.

```
DatabaseDAO dbDAO = new DatabaseDAO();
dbDAO.initConnection();
```

Second, create both Employee and Product class with the DatabaseDAO instance as a parameter.

```
Employee emp = new Employee(dbDAO);
Product prd = new Product(dbDAO);
```

Finally, you can retrieve the data from both instance of class by calling methods, getEmployeeList and getProductList each then close the connection owned by the DAO class.

```
try {
    emplist = emp.getEmployeeList();
    prdlist = prd.getProductList();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    dbDAO.closeConnection();
}
```

The structure of the classes would be the same,
For example, the getProductList() looks:

```
public List<ProductDto> getProductList() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<ProductDto> prd = new ArrayList<ProductDto>();

    rs = dataDAO.getalldetails(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        ProductDto qd = new ProductDto();
        qd.setProdid(rs.getInt("prodid"));
        qd.setProdname(rs.getString("prodname"));
        qd.setItem(rs.getString("item"));
        prd.add(qd);
    }

    rs.close();

    return prd;
}
```

You can call getalldetails method in the DatabaseDAO instance and make the resultset a list of dto object.

The Employee and Product class:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee {
    private static final String query = "Select * from Employee";

    final DatabaseDAO dataDAO;

    Employee(final DatabaseDAO dataDAO) {
        this.dataDAO = dataDAO;
    }

    public List<EmployeeDto> getEmployeeList() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<EmployeeDto> emp = new ArrayList<EmployeeDto>();

        rs = dataDAO.getalldetails(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            EmployeeDto qd = new EmployeeDto();
            qd.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            qd.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            qd.setRollno(rs.getString("rollno"));
            emp.add(qd);
        }

        rs.close();

        return emp;
    }

}

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Product {

    private static final String query = "Select * from Product";

    final DatabaseDAO dataDAO;

    Product(final DatabaseDAO dataDAO) {
        this.dataDAO = dataDAO;
    }

    public List<ProductDto> getProductList() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<ProductDto> prd = new ArrayList<ProductDto>();

        rs = dataDAO.getalldetails(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            ProductDto qd = new ProductDto();
            qd.setProdid(rs.getInt("prodid"));
            qd.setProdname(rs.getString("prodname"));
            qd.setItem(rs.getString("item"));
            prd.add(qd);
        }

        rs.close();

        return prd;
    }
}
```

The Dao class - DatabaseDAO, this class has a structure only, you can make your connection object depending on databases.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DatabaseDAO {
    private Connection con;

    public DatabaseDAO()
    {

    }

    public void initConnection()
    {

    }

    public Connection getDBConnection()
    {
        return con;
    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        try {
            this.con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getalldetails(String query) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs;
    }
}
```

The main method class here:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

public class DBMain {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DatabaseDAO dbDAO = new DatabaseDAO();
        dbDAO.initConnection();

        Employee emp = new Employee(dbDAO);
        Product prd = new Product(dbDAO);
        List<EmployeeDto> emplist = null;
        List<ProductDto> prdlist = null;

        try {
            emplist = emp.getEmployeeList();
            prdlist = prd.getProductList();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            dbDAO.closeConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the dto classes left, EmpolyeeDto and ProductDto might be as follows:

```
public class EmployeeDto {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String rollno;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(String rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }


}

public class ProductDto {
     private int prodid;
     private String prodname;
     private String item;

    public int getProdid() {
        return prodid;
    }
    public void setProdid(int prodid) {
        this.prodid = prodid;
    }
    public String getProdname() {
        return prodname;
    }
    public void setProdname(String prodname) {
        this.prodname = prodname;
    }
    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }


}
```